# sending e-mail via PHP in Bluemix

Tags: php, email, ibm-cloud

I use this short code to send a simple confirmation e-mail to a user who has forgotten their password and has click "generate new password"

```
mail($email,'password recovery','Your temporary password is '.$generatedpassword ,'From: do_not_reply@do_not_reply.com');
```

It works just fine on my private server but when I pushed my PHP code to BlueMix the users never get that e-mail.

As I mentioned above the code works just fine on my server, which leads me to believe that this is a BlueMix specific issue.

Comment: Hello, Epodax. Thank you for that nice little minus there but as I mentioned above the code works just fine on my server, which leads me to believe that this is a BlueMix specific issue.

Comment: Hi, please don't presume that I was the one to down vote, it makes you look like a ass, SO is not a "fix my code with a very vague issue description service".

Comment: haha, you know what? you're right. Sorry about that. Yeah I know the question might seem vague but I am hoping it will get answered by a very specific person / people who I think will know what's up. Have a great day E.

Comment: How is your local server configured? Are you using an SMTP server to send the e-mail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That line works in your environment since you probably have a mail server configured and available there. There is no such default configuration available on Bluemix.

Your options are:

- deploy the application on Bluemix and then point to your own server (e.g. using the public IP)
- use [Sendgrid](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/sendgrid/) (available directly from the Bluemix Catalog) or similar e-mail services

Comment: When deploying the application on Bluemix, make sure you are not using port 25 because that's blocked (see also http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/outbound-email-port-25)